# Issue with Puma when installing Rails on a Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, puma, rbenv

I'm trying to install Rails on my new machine, and I keep getting this error when bundling.

```
An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  puma
```

When I run `gem install puma -v '4.3.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/`, I get this error:

---

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/christopherdavis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
/Users/christopherdavis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/christopherdavis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200829-23175-2h0q0u.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
checking for DTLS_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for TLS_server_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version in openssl/ssl.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/christopherdavis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/christopherdavis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:44:18: warning: unused variable 'puma_parser_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int puma_parser_en_main = 1;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c:145:7: warning: unused variable 'min' [-Wunused-variable]
  int min, ssl_options;
      ^
mini_ssl.c:299:40: warning: function 'raise_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]
void raise_error(SSL* ssl, int result) {
                                       ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling puma_http11.c
puma_http11.c:203:22: error: implicitly declaring library function 'isspace' with type 'int (int)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  while (vlen > 0 && isspace(value[vlen - 1])) vlen--;
                     ^
puma_http11.c:203:22: note: include the header <ctype.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'isspace'
1 error generated.
make: *** [puma_http11.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/christopherdavis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/christopherdavis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.7.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out
```

---

Has anyone seen this before? How might I fix the issue? I'm new to Rails and unsure of what's going on. I followed the tutorial on GoRails and found myself here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

See https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/2314

Run this line...

bundle config build.puma --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

Comment: Here's the [direct link](https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/2314#issuecomment-672006973) to the comment in that PR that gives this answer, if you want to like it there as well. It's caused by Xcode 12.